# VBA macro for Excel format tables a specific way

Tags: vba, excel

I need help writing a macro. Basically, we export an excel spreadsheet from our payroll system that looks something like this:

```
LastName    FirstName   EMail   PayType Hours   ActualWages PayRate Shift   
DOE         JOHN        FORD    1       37.5    721.13      19.23   1   
DOE         JOHN        FORD    2       5       144.25      19.23   1   
DOE         JOHN        FORD    22      0       5           19.23   1   
DOE         JOHN        FORD    15      7.5     144.23      19.23   1   
DOE         JOHN        FORD    13      7.5     144.23      19.23   1   
DONALD      NANCY       PARKS   1       40      1346        1346    1   
DONALD      NANCY       PARKS   13      8       269.2       1346    1   
DONALD      NANCY       PARKS   22      0       25          1346    1   
DONALD      NANCY       PARKS   15      8       269.2       1346    1
```

I want the macro to format the table into one row per person. The variable that has to change is the PayType, and here is what each pay type is: PayType 1 = Reg, PayType 2 = OT (overtime), PayType 13 = Vac, PayType 15 = Hol, PayType 22 = Reimb.

I have a huge list of employees that take up too many rows and it is hard to read with the paytypes. I want to reduce the amount of rows to one per person, and instead of having the PayType column, replace that with RegHrs (value of PayType 1), O/THrs, and HolHrs. All the other columns stay the same.

The trickiest part that I can't figure out is how to check each row, if the person is the same, just copy values, if its a different person, start new row. The copy part I have down, I just need help on checking for each employee. I don't ever do macros, this is just a once a year thing that will automate repetitive tasks.

I thank you all in advance. If you have questions, message me. I know the question is confusing.

Comment: why not use a pivot table...not sure a macro will help

Comment: What about PayType 13 = Vac, and PayType 22 = Reimb ? Where do you want to place them ?

Comment: They would be their own separate column. The point of the macro is to reduce the number of rows, even if it means adding some more columns. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FinalTableFormat()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastRowDJ As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("Test_Execution").Cells(Worksheets("Test_Execution").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowDJ = Worksheets("Defect_JIRAs").Cells(Worksheets("Defect_JIRAs").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Test_Execution")
        .Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 11.29
        .Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 45
        .Range("C1").ColumnWidth = 11.78
        .Range("D1").ColumnWidth = 45
        .Range("E1").ColumnWidth = 9.57
        .Range("F1").ColumnWidth = 15
        .Range("G1").ColumnWidth = 45
    End With

    With Worksheets("Defect_JIRAs")
        .Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 11.29
        .Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 45
        .Range("C1").ColumnWidth = 11.78
        .Range("D1").ColumnWidth = 45
        .Range("E1").ColumnWidth = 9.57
        .Range("F1").ColumnWidth = 15
        .Range("G1").ColumnWidth = 45
        .Range("A1:G" & LastRowDJ).Rows.AutoFit
    End With

    With Worksheets("Status_Report")
        .Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 11.29
        .Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Range("C1").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Range("D1").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Range("E1").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Range("F1").ColumnWidth = 11
        .Range("G1").ColumnWidth = 11
        .Range("H1").ColumnWidth = 11
        .Range("I1").ColumnWidth = 11
        .Range("J1").ColumnWidth = 11.29
    End With

    Range("A1:O18").Rows.AutoFit

    With Range("A1:G" & LastRow)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
       .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
    End With

    With Range("A1:G1")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub StatusReport_TestingTable()

    Dim TotalTC As Integer, PassedTC As Long, ExecutedTC As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim PassPerc As Double, ExecPerc As Double
    Dim wrkrow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("Test_Execution").Cells(Worksheets("Test_Execution").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    TotalTC = Worksheets("Test_JIRAs").Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Rows.Count
    PassedTC = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D1:D" & LastRow), "PASS")
    ExecutedTC = PassedTC + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D1:D" & LastRow), "FAIL")
    PassPerc = Format(PassedTC / TotalTC * 100, "#.00")
    ExecPerc = Format(ExecutedTC / TotalTC * 100, "#.00")
    wrkrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Planned Start Date", Worksheets("Status_Report").Range("B1:B500"), 0)
    Worksheets("Status_Report").Range("G" & wrkrow + 1) = TotalTC
    Worksheets("Status_Report").Range("H" & wrkrow + 1) = PassPerc / 100
    Worksheets("Status_Report").Range("I" & wrkrow + 1) = ExecPerc / 100

End Sub
```